Show actual duration of audio files
I have to display the audios actual time for books under most popular category.
I am saving my files on Firebase and getting it as URL. I don't have any other metadata saved to determine the duration the exact duration of fetched files.
{
  /* Duration */
}
<Typography
  variant="body2"
  gutterBottom
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
  }}
>
  <IconButton
    style={{ marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", marginTop: "5px" }}
  >
    <Headset />
  </IconButton>
  <span
    style={{
      borderBottom: "1px solid #000",
      top: 10,
      flexGrow: 1,
      marginRight: "10px",
    }}
  />
  {19} min
</Typography>;

I'm using this useEffect to fetch the books:
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchRatings = async () => {
    const ratings: Record<string, number> = {};
    for (const product of products) {
      const avgRating = await getAverageRating(product.bk_ID);
      ratings[product.bk_ID] = avgRating;
    }
    setAverageRatings(ratings);
  };
  fetchRatings();
}, [products]);

const sortedProducts = products.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  const ratingA = averageRatings[a.bk_ID] || 0;
  const ratingB = averageRatings[b.bk_ID] || 0;

  return ratingB - ratingA;
});

